# Pivot Kind Of Table In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Can we bring the pivot kind of table (column wise) without doing a sub-query in MySQL? I think Pivot option is not available in mysql even now.

Option#1 - Create temp table and query via Stored procedure
Option#2 - Is it possible without sub-query

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and your desired output in the table formats; it would be easy for people to understand

Comment: You may pivot your data using GROUP BY and conditional aggregation.